Extending a bounded linear functional using Hahn-Banach, subject to conditions on two norms
While Hahn-Banach theorem is incredibly powerful, it is known, in general, that Hahn-Banach theorem does not really allow one to extend a linear functional subject to conditions on two distinct norms. For example, let $V = \mathbb{R}^2$, $W = \mathbb{R}e_1 \subset V$, and $\varphi: W \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $\varphi(re_1) = r$. Then $\varphi$ has norm $1$ under the restrictions of the following two norms on $V$: the $\ell^\infty$ norm w.r.t. the standard basis, and the $\ell^\infty$ norm w.r.t. the basis $\{e_1, e_1 + e_2\}$. But, no extension of $\varphi$ to $V$ can have norm $1$ under both norms simultaneously.
However, out of curiosity, I was wondering if something weaker might be true, namely, instead of insisting the norms of the functional be preserved under both norms, we want an extension that preserves the norm of the functional under one norm and only stays bounded under the other. Now, if there are no conditions whatsoever on the two norms, this is impossible. If I'm not mistaken, one can simply choose a linear space and two norms on it so that the topological duals induced by two norms intersect trivially, then no nonzero linear functional can be bounded simultaneously under the two norms. If, instead, we ask the two norms be equivalent, then the result is trivially true. What, then, if we ask one of the norms be dominated by the other but not the other way around? Formally, we have the following question:

Suppose $V$ is a real or complex vector space, $\|\cdot\|_1$ and $\|\cdot\|_2$ are two norms on $V$ s.t. $\|\cdot\|_1 \leq C\|\cdot\|_2$ for some $C > 0$. Suppose $W \subset V$ is a subspace and $\varphi$ is a linear functional on $W$ which is bounded under $\|\cdot\|_1$ and has norm $R$ for some $0 < R < \infty$ under $\|\cdot\|_2$. Does there exist $\psi$, linear functional on $V$, which extends $\varphi$, s.t. $\psi$ is bounded under $\|\cdot\|_1$ and has norm $R$ under $\|\cdot\|_2$?

I attempted to consider norms that are a blend of $\|\cdot\|_1$ and $\|\cdot\|_2$, then apply the usual Hahn-Banach, to no avail.

Extensions described in OP may not exist. In the example below it is more convenient to switch the roles of the norms.
Let $V=\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$ and $$W=\left \{x\in \ell^1(\mathbb{N})\,: \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n=0\right \}$$ We have $\|x\|_2\le \|x\|_1.$  Let $\varphi(x)=2x_1.$ Then $|\varphi(x)|\le\|x\|_1$ for $x\in W$ as $$\varphi(x)=x_1-\sum_{n=2}^\infty  x_n$$ Actually the norm of $\varphi$ with respect to $\|\cdot\|_1$ is equal $1,$ because
$$\varphi(\delta_1-\delta_2)=2,\quad \|\delta_1-\delta_2\|_1=2 $$
The subspace $W$ is dense in $\ell^2(\mathbb{N}).$ Therefore any extension  $\widetilde{\varphi}$   to $V,$ bounded with respect to $\|\cdot\|_2,$ must be equal $\widetilde{\varphi}(x)=2x_1,$ i.e. its norm with respect to $\|\cdot\|_1$ is equal $2.$

That’s a fantastic example. Thanks!
